# PHP If condition with a week prior to today's date range

Tags: php

So basically, I want to figure out how I can get today's date in PHP. Essentially what function can I use to get it.

I tried the following: `strtotime('now')` but that gives me a number like this `1362992653` which I can't really work with.

I am trying to get today's date in the following format `20130311` so year/month/day that way I could just subtract 7 from it. So my if statement would look something like this

```
$todaydate = some function;
$mydate = 20130311 <-- will be in this format;
$oneweekprior = $todaydate - 7;

if ($mydate > $oneweekprior && $mydate < $todaysdate) { 

    then do my stuff; 

}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the `date()` function. And get used to reading the documentation all the time. That number is called a UNIX timestamp and can be used to make calculations easily with dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$todayEpoch = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$mydate = strtotime('20130311');

$oneweekprior = $todayEpoch - 7*24*60*60;

if ($mydate > $oneweekprior && $mydate < $todaysdate) { 

    then do my stuff; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That number you're getting is, so called, unix timestamp - number of seconds since 01.01.1970 and mainly it is what you should use to do things you want to do:

```
$todaydate = time(); // same as strtotime('now'), but without overhead of parsing 'now'
$mydate = strtotime('20130311'); // turn your date into timestamp
$oneweekprior = $todaydate - 7*24*60*60; // today - one week in seconds
// or
//$oneweekprior = strtotime('-7 days');

if ($mydate > $oneweekprior && $mydate < $todaysdate) {
    // do something
}
```

to turn timestamp back into human readable form use `strftime` or `date` function:

```
echo strftime('%Y%m%d', $todaydate);
```

and please read [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) for date functions in PHP

---

The idea with comparing dates like you wanted to is pretty bad, lets assume that today is `20130301` and date to check is `20130228` - with your solution it would be:

```
$mydate = 20130228;
$today = 20130301;
$weekago = $today - 7;

// $mydate should pass this test, but it won't because $weekago is equal 20130294 !!
if ($mydate > $weekago && $mydate < $today) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    $now = time();

    $one_week_ago  = $now - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 );
    $date_today    = date( 'Ymd', $now );
    $date_week_ago = date( 'Ymd', $one_week_ago );

    echo 'today: '    . $date_today    . '<br /><br />';
    echo 'week-ago: ' . $date_week_ago . '<br /><br />';
```

The time you were getting from strtotime('now') is called the **[Epoch Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)** (*or Unix time \ POSIX time*), which is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970. So, time() gives you this number as well, which you can then subtract 1 week worth of seconds from to get the epoch time from a week ago.

→ For more information on **date()** including different strings like 'Ymd' for date formats, please visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php